# Braintree Apple sandbox Pay shows payment not completed error after scanning finger prints iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay, braintree-sandbox

I have implemented Braintree which supports Apple Pay. But I am facing a problem. Everything is running properly but whenever I try to make payment it shows me the "Payment not completed" sign. I have checked that my domain is verified. I have called the Apple Pay button with this below code.

```
- (PKPaymentRequest *)paymentRequest
{
    PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [[PKPaymentRequest alloc] init];
    paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.myIdentifier";
    //paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.mysandboxIdentifier";
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = @[PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard];
    paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability3DS;
    paymentRequest.countryCode = @"US"; // e.g. US
    paymentRequest.currencyCode = @"USD"; // e.g. USD
//    self.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressFieldPostalAddress;
//    paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressFieldAll;

//    paymentRequest.shippingMethods = [self ShipingMethod];

//    paymentRequest.shippingContact = [self ShipingAddress:@"Delivered" :paymentRequest];
   paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [self PaymentSummaryItems];
    return paymentRequest;
}


- (IBAction)applePayButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender
{

    self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    self.iconLoadingIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [self.iconLoadingIndicator startAnimating];

    backBtn.enabled = NO;
    self.applePayBtn.enabled = NO;
    self.creditCardBtn.enabled = NO;
    self.checkoutBtn.enabled = NO;

    if([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:@[PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkVisa,PKPaymentNetworkDiscover]]) // Returns FALSE
    {
        if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePayments])
        {
            PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [self paymentRequest];
            PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *vc = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:paymentRequest];
            if (vc)
            {
                self.payment_mode = kApplePayMode;
                vc.delegate = self;
                [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

            }
            else
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Something went wrong. Please Try Again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
               [self StopLoader];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Your card does not support Apple Pay." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

       [self StopLoader];
    }
}
```

This delegate is not calling as it stuck in payment is not completed process.[image]

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                       didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                                   handler:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationResult *result))completion API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0), watchos(4.0));
{
    isApplePayInitiatingPayment = YES;

    // Example: Tokenize the Apple Pay payment
    BTApplePayClient *applePayClient = [[BTApplePayClient alloc]
                                        initWithAPIClient:self.braintreeClient];
    [applePayClient tokenizeApplePayPayment:payment
                                 completion:^(BTApplePayCardNonce *tokenizedApplePayPayment,
                                              NSError *error)
     {
         if (tokenizedApplePayPayment)
         {
             // On success, send nonce to your server for processing.
             // If applicable, address information is accessible in `payment`.
             NSLog(@"nonce = %@", tokenizedApplePayPayment.nonce);
             self.wcitiesBraintreeCreateTransaction = [[WcitiesBraintreeCreateTransaction alloc] init];
             [self.wcitiesBraintreeCreateTransaction CreateTransaction:self.totalPrice OneTimeNonce:tokenizedApplePayPayment.nonce paypal_payer_id:@"" payment_mode:kApplePayMode :^(NSMutableArray *result, NSError *error)
              {
                  if (result.count>0)
                  {
                      self.transaction_id = [result objectAtIndex:0];
                      [self generateClientOrder:NO];
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Transaction failure. Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                      [alert show];
                      [self StopLoader];
                  }
              }];


             // Then indicate success or failure via the completion callback, e.g.
             PKPaymentAuthorizationResult *result = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationResult alloc] initWithStatus:PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess errors:nil];
             completion(result);
         } else {
             // Tokenization failed. Check `error` for the cause of the failure.

             // Indicate failure via the completion callback:
             PKPaymentAuthorizationResult *result = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationResult alloc] initWithStatus:PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure errors:nil];
             completion(result);
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Transaction failure. Please try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
             [alert show];
             [self StopLoader];
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: I would like to warn you not to use Braintree. After many years of having an account they started requesting ridiculous amounts of paperwork for the most simple transactions - and we never had any disputes or chargebacks! I found out later they are owned by Paypal, so that probably says it all.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your precious experience. Will definitely talk with my team about it. But at least if you can help me with my current scenario that would be really great full :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different test credit card from Apple. https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/

I was having this issue as well and got around it by trying different cards until one of them worked.

Comment: I know its bit late to reply, but had tried different Apples card not working. The App development belongs to India region, so I thought may be region would be problem so I change the device region to US and UK from device setting, also I tried to use VPN but nothing worked.